# Can I set env key from param in template

Tags: openshift

in OpenShift 4.3, I'm trying to set env key from param value within a template. for example:

```
"env": [
  {
    "name: "${FOO}-TEST",
    "value": "${BAR}"
  },
  {
    "name: "TEST",
    "value": "${BAR}"
  }
]

"parameters": [
  {
    "name": "FOO",
    "required": true
  },
  {
    "name": "BAR",
    "required": true
  }
]
```

Then, oc new-app with -p FOO=X -p BAR=Y, and checking env vars on pod, it shows:

```
TEST=Y
```

But does not show:

```
X-TEST=Y
```

In template, can I not include a parameter value as env key?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set up a parameter value as env key.
Could you check the template is working well as you expected as follows ?

1. export the template as yaml file first.

`$ oc get template <your template name> -o yaml > test-template.yml`

2. check whether the parameter you specified is setting up or not from the output.

`$ oc process -f test-template.yml -p FOO=X -p BAR=Y`

It's my simple test result.
e.g.>

```
$ cat test-temp.yml
:
        containers:
        - env:
          - name: "${NAME}-KEY"
            value: ${NAME}
:

$ oc process -f test-temp.yml -p NAME=test
:                        
                        "containers": [
                            {
                                "env": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "test-KEY",
                                        "value": "test"
                                    }
                                ],
:
```

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

- Export your variables

  oc process  FOO=${FOO} BAR=${BAR} -f yamlFile